# Implement pull to refresh FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

please help me out to implement pull to refresh on my app, I'm kinda new to react native, thanks. I don't know how to handle onRefresh and refreshing.

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
  state = { refreshing: false }

  _renderItem = ({ item }) => <ImageGrid item={item} />

  _handleRefresh = () => {

  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    if (data.loading) {
      return (
        <Root>
          <Loading size="large" />
        </Root>
      )
    }
 return (
   <Root>
     <HomeHeader />
     <FlatList
       contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
       data={data.getPosts}
       keyExtractor={item => item._id}
       renderItem={this._renderItem}
       numColumns={3}
       refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
       onRefresh={this._handleRefresh}
     />
   </Root>
  );
 }
}

export default graphql(GET_POSTS_QUERY)(HomeScreen);
```

Answer (score 111):

Set variable

```
this.state = { 
    isFetching: false,
}
```

Create Refresh function

```
onRefresh() {
    this.setState({isFetching: true,},() => {this.getApiData();});
}
```

And in last set onRefresh and refreshing in FlatList.

```
<FlatList
    data={ this.state.FlatListItems }
    onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
    refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
/>
```

After fetching Data in function getApiData Make sure to set false isFetching.

```
this.setState({ isFetching: false })
```

Comment: Hey @Krish i do it , but last item in Data it can't disappear and when i pull to refresh the "loading" stuck and can't get new data!

Comment: @DevAS  Empty the array(when you setstate blank array flatlist must reload) before calling reload function and check if still your FlatList is showing last item or not.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean :/ you said empty the array when call onRefresh?

Comment: @DevAS I mean Empty the array (in my example "FlatListItems"), it must refresh the Flatlist and should not show the last the last item. 
Please share code so that i can review it.

Answer (score 28):

You can also use `refreshControl` in `Flatlist`, `ScrollView`, and any other list component.

```
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{ alignSelf: 'stretch' }}
  data={data.getPosts}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
  renderItem={this._renderItem}
  numColumns={3}
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
      refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
      onRefresh={this._handleRefresh}
    />
  }
/>
```

Comment: if you set <FlatList /> prop `onRefresh`, FlatList will set `RefreshControl` automatically, althouth it's a default one.

Answer (score 14):

If someone is interested in doing it with React Hooks here is it:

First create `isRefreshing` state:

```
const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false)
```

Then create your `onRefresh` function that calls API to refresh data:

```
const onRefresh = () => {
    //set isRefreshing to true
    setIsRefreshing(true)
    callApiMethod()
    // and set isRefreshing to false at the end of your callApiMethod()
}
```

And after that, your `FlatList` component that looks like that:

```
return (
    <FlatList
        style={styles.flatList}
        onRefresh={onRefresh}
        refreshing={isRefreshing}
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 10):

// Sample code representing pull to refresh in flatlist. Modify accordingly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Text, View,StyleSheet,FlatList,Dimensions,Image,TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'

    export default class Home extends Component {

        constructor(props) 
        {
            super(props);
        this.state = {
            data : [],
            gender : "",
            isFetching: false,
        }
        }

    componentWillMount()
    {

        this.searchRandomUser()
    }

    onRefresh() {
        this.setState({ isFetching: true }, function() { this.searchRandomUser() });
     }

    searchRandomUser = async () =>
    {
       const RandomAPI = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20')
       const APIValue = await RandomAPI.json();
        const APIResults = APIValue.results
          console.log(APIResults[0].email);
          this.setState({
              data:APIResults,
              isFetching: false
          })

    }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style = {styles.container}>
     <TouchableHighlight
     onPressOut = {this.searchRandomUser}
         style = {{width:deviceWidth - 32, height:45,backgroundColor: 'green',justifyContent:"center",alignContent:"center"}}>
              <Text style = {{fontSize:22,color: 'white',fontWeight: 'bold',textAlign:"center"}}>Reload Data</Text>
         </TouchableHighlight>
     <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
          refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
            keyExtractor = { (item, index) => index.toString() }
            renderItem={({item}) =>
            <View style = {styles.ContainerView}>
            <View>
    <Image
    source={{uri : item.picture.large}}
    style = {{height:100,width:100,borderRadius: 50,marginLeft: 4}}
    resizeMode='contain'
    />
    </View>

    <View style = {{flexDirection: 'column',marginLeft:16,marginRight: 16,flexWrap:'wrap',alignSelf:"center",width: deviceWidth-160}}>
    <Text>Email Id : {item.email}</Text>

    <Text>Full Name : {this.state.gender} {item.name.first} {item.name.last}</Text>
    <Text>Date of birth : {item.dob.age}</Text>
    <Text>Phone number : {item.phone}</Text>

    </View>

    </View>
            }
            />
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
    const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
    const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          marginTop:22
        },
        ContainerView:
        {
            // backgroundColor:'grey',
            marginBottom:20,
            paddingVertical:10,
            backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5',

            borderBottomWidth:0.5,
            borderBottomColor:'grey',
            width: deviceWidth-40,
            marginLeft:20,
            marginRight:20,
            marginTop:20,
            flexDirection:'row'
        }
      });
```

Comment: Example For Above Code, Thanks@Rishav Kumar, Link =>  https://snack.expo.io/tzvapUOLa

Answer (score 8):

```
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false)
    
 <FlatList
     style={{ padding: 15 }}
     refreshControl={
         <RefreshControl 
             refreshing={refreshing} 
             onRefresh={_onRefresh}
             tintColor="#F8852D"/>
     }
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
     data={listData}
     renderItem={renderItem}
     item={(item, index) => index.toStirng()}
     onEndReachedThreshold={0.8}
     onEndReached={() => onEndReached()}
     ListFooterComponent={() => renderFooter()}
 />
```

> _onRefresh Function

```
const _onRefresh = () => {
    console.log('_onRefresh')
    setRefreshing(true);
    getPosts();
};
```

Comment: `refreshing` and `onRefresh` are already FlatList props. Do you still need to wrap in it a `RefreshControl` tag?

Comment: @deepanshu please correct the spelling of **index.toStirng()** to **index.toString()**

Comment: import { RefreshControl } from 'react-native';

Answer (score 1):

"Pull to refresh" concept implies that the list can be manually refreshed thus can be changed outside the current view (e.g. fetched from server). So the callback `onRefresh` has to trigger the data reloading process (e.g. send a request to the server) and set the `refreshing` variable to truthy value. This will notify the user that the process was started by showing loading indicator. Once you got the data ready you need to set `refreshing` to falsy so the view will hide loading indicator.

Answer (score 1):

this is the best that I can do. [my Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yav59.png)

when I pull it down it dosen't refetch data from server I'm running graphql server which connected by Apollo to the app, and I don't know how to get data from server in _getData() function.

Comment: It would be helpful if you paste the code snippet here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using pull to refresh on flat-list simply use on Scroll View.

Set Refresh State

```
this.state = { 
     isFetching: false,
  }
```

Set onFresh in ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
      refreshing={this.state.refresh}
      onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
      tintColor="red"
    />
  }>
  <FlatList data={data} renderItem={this._renderItem} numColumns={3} />
</ScrollView>;
```

In OnRefreshFunction

```
  onRefresh() {
    this.setState({refresh: true});
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({refresh: false});
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: The question is specifically for how to do it for FlatList, not what the alternatives to FlatList are.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the official document:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol

Answer (score 1):

### For anyone looking for an updated answer using new React Hooks.

You can use `isLoading` and `refetch` from `useQuery`.
Then use `RefreshControl` with `FlatList`. Read more on `RefreshControl`: https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol

```
const RenderImageGrid = (item) => <ImageGrid item={item} />

export const HomeScreen = () => {
    const { data, isLoading, refetch } = useQuery('get_home_screen_data', GET_HOME_SCREEN_DATA)
    return (
        {isLoading ? (
            <Root>
                <Loading size="large" />
            </Root>
        ) : (
            <Root>
                <HomeHeader />
                <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    keyExtractor={item => item._id}
                    renderItem={RenderImageGrid}
                    numColumns={3}
                    refreshControl={
                        <RefreshControl 
                            refreshing={isLoading}
                            onRefresh={refetch} 
                        />
                    }
                />
            </Root>
        )}
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```