# React native pull down refresh to fetch data

Tags: javascript, react-native, page-refresh

I am using React native to show the data from fetch API. But when the data update, it still shows the old data. I'm confusing how to do the pull down refresh inside my code.

```
class YourActivitiesScreen extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activitiesList: [],   
        }
    };
    componentDidMount(){
        AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token').then(this.getData)
    }
    getData=(token)=>{
        console.log(token)
       fetch('http://192.168.0.1:8887/api/auth/activities/your',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +token,
            },
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())

        .then((res) => {
            if(res.yourActivity)
            {
                let yourActivity = res.yourActivity
                this.setState({activitiesList: yourActivity})
            }
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('Error: ', e))
        }
        renderItem = (item) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => 
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('Details',{activity: item})
                }
              >
                <View style={styles.item}>
                  <Text style={styles.itemtext}>{item.name} </Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }
    render(){
        const listActivities = this.state.activitiesList

        return (
                <View stlye={styles.container}>
                    <SafeAreaView>
                        <FlatList
                            data = {listActivities}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderItem(item)}
                            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                            style={styles.list}
                        />
                    </SafeAreaView>
                </View>
        )
        }
}
```

Is that i need to do something to let the componentDidMount run again while I make a pull down action? If yes can someone explain to me how to do so?

Comment: you can use refreshcontrol for pull donw refresh see https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [`extraData`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) [`FlatList`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) prop each time you update the data.

> ### [`extraData`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata)
>
> A marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it implements `PureComponent`). If any of your `renderItem`, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the `data` prop, stick it here and treat it immutably.

Set `extraData` prop with the `activitiesList` object:

```
render(){
  const listActivities = this.state.activitiesList

  return (
    <View stlye={styles.container}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList
          data={listActivities}
          extraData={listActivities}
          renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderItem(item)}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          style={styles.list}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `onRefresh` prop in FlatList. Ref: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onrefresh
Note: Please make sure to set the `refreshing` prop correctly when use `onRefresh` in FlatList.

[Implement pull to refresh FlatList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570998/implement-pull-to-refresh-flatlist)

Comment: Please check this link for more info - https://enappd.com/blog/refreshcontrol-pull-to-refresh-in-react-native-apps/130/