# React Native RefreshControl for all application screens

Tags: react-native, pull-to-refresh

According to the documentation i would have to implement RefreshControl on every screen of my app on ScrollView or FlatList.

Is there any way to wrap all my application with RefreshControl component?

Answer (score 2):

Yes just make your own Flatlist component with refresh control and pass the same props the normal Flatlist takes then call it wherever you use a flatlist

Answer (score 0):

you can use prop `onRefresh` for swipe refresh

```
<FlatList
    data={ this.state.FlatListItems }
    onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
    refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
/>
```

for more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570998/implement-pull-to-refresh-flatlist)